# Open a directory using specific path

Tags: c++

How to open a location of file in local machine using a specific path in C++?

Path as input:
`D:downloads/sample.txt`

Output: after executing, file should be opened automatically.

Comment: This question is very unclear. Do you just want to know how to [open a file](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/)? Btw, this differs a lot from how you would do it in [tag:c], so please don't add irrelevant tags!

Comment: You look confused. A file path is *not* an URL.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that [directories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)) (or "folders") are unknown to the C++11 or C++14 standards. C++17 has a [`std::filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) namespace from `<filesystem>` standard header.

Notice also that on [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows) the directory separator in [file paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)) is a backslash `\` (but on POSIX and Linux it is a forward slash `/`). Some runtime systems (and C++ standard libraries) might convert forward slashes `/` to backslashes `\` in file paths on Windows. Check your documentation to see if your implementation does that conversion.

Many framework libraries (including [Qt](http://qt.io/) & [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) & [Boost](http://boost.org/)) provide abstractions related to directories, files, paths and file systems.

I don't have Windows (I'm happy to only use Linux both at work and at home), but I guess that you could pass `D:downloads\sample.txt` as a path for [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream). Of course you'll need to escape the backslash in your literal string:

```
std::ifstream myinput("D:downloads\\sample.txt");
```

<sup>(I guess that the `downloads` should start with a capital `Downloads`, but I leave you to check that, also on French systems it might be a different directory `Téléchargements` but you should check; I would recommend using some *absolute* file path like `D:\Downloads\sample.txt`; of course you'll need to escape both backslashes in a literal string)</sup>

Notice that a file path is not an [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) (but URLs *starting* with the `file:` scheme designate a local file thru its file path). AFAIK you need some external library to handle such URLs. If you insist on giving full URLs, you'll better in practice use some [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) client library (e.g. [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)), because most URLs are for HTTP.

You might later test that the input stream is correctly opened:

```
if (!myinput.is_opened())
    throw throw std::runtime("failed to open myinput");
```

Then you could parse from it using the [operator >>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) for instance

```
int x=0;
myinput >> x;
```

You could later use the unary [operator !](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!) to check against input parsing failures.

Comment: Nice answer, just a note on a possible pitfall: Windows has a current directory **per drive**, so writing `D:downloads\\sample.txt` is the path relative to whatever is the current directory on drive `D`. Better write `D:\\downloads\\sample.txt`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: the note after the first code snippet said that.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: also, even MS-DOS had a current directory *per drive*.

Comment: Ahh, I tend to mentally ignore *small text* ;) And of course, this strange thing has historic reasons....